# Keyboard Shortcuts in Coda

Tags: macos, mac, coda

Using Coda, the all-in-one web editor developed by Panic for OSX, I find myself utilizing a lot of keyboard shortcuts. Particularly the *Publish* shortcut **(<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)**. The only problem with this shortcut is that it publishes the highlighted file in the file browser, NOT my file currently open in the editor. This brings me to two questions that could potentially circumvent this - please feel free to post any other solutions though.

**Possible choice 1:**
Is it possible to modify the preferences to make the publish shortcut publish the active file in the editor?

**Possible choice 2:**
Is there a keyboard shortcut for the *Show in File Browser* command? I don't see it listed in the keyboard shortcuts in the help menu.

Answer (score 2):

Coda doesn't seem to offer either of your suggestions. So let's just create our own command and add it to Coda.

---

In Coda, *Show Scripts menu* in *General* preferences.

[image]

Open `/Applications/Utilities/AppleScript Editor.app`, create a new document, and paste the following:

```
tell application "Coda"
    tell document 1
        upload item full name of current editor
    end tell
end tell
```

This script will upload the file currently being edited and clear its *locally modified* state. `document 1` seems to always be the frontmost Coda window in my limited testing.

Save as `~/Library/Scripts/Applications/Coda/Upload Tab.scpt` (if you don't find Library, press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> in the file browser or just *Open Enclosing Folder* in Coda's scripts menu). Select *Reload Scripts* in Coda's scripts menu and make sure the new command is in there.

---

Assign a keyboard shortcut in *System Preferences*.

[image]

---

Here's the new command in Coda:

[image]

---

Coda will ask you what to do if the file already exists on the remote site. Just append `with resume mode overwrite` (labeled *Replace* in the GUI; the other options being `skip` and `resume`) to the `upload` command in AppleScript.

Comment: What I didn't do here is fancy error handling and such. Coda shows  useful error message itself (*File does not exist*) for unsaved documents (*Untitled.html*), and useless error messages if you don't have an active editor, open window, or no remote connection. Just limit your use of the command to when it actually makes sense.

Comment: Awesome. And the message asking whether coda should overwrite the file only appears if we use the upload command, I haven't had a chance to try this yet, but my hope is that if I change `upload item full name of current editor` to `publish item full name of current editor` it may fix our issue.

Comment: @anwyatt I really didn't see the `publish` command. You're right, of course.